# How do I use SQL to select rows that have > 50 related rows in another table?

Tags: sql

I've been trying to find out how to write this query in SQL.

What I need is to find the productnames (in the products table) that have 50 or more orders (which are in the order table).

Only one orderid is matched up to a productname at a time so when I try to count the orderid's it counts all of them.

I can get distinct productnames but once I add in the orderid's then it goes back to having multiple productnames.

I also need to count the number of customers (in the order table) that have ordered those products.

```
Table: Products
      `productname` in the form of a text like 'GrannySmith'

Table: Orders
      `orderid` in the form of '10222'..etc
      `custid` in the form of something like 'SMITH'
```

Comment: what is the column that relates the products to its orders? can you post the entire schema? Also what DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the orders table has a field that relates back to the products table named ProductId. The SQL would translate to:

```
SELECT p.ProductName, Count(*)
FROM Orders o 
JOIN Products p
  on o.ProductId = p.ProductId
GROUP BY p.ProductName HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50
```

The key is in the `having` component of the Group By clause. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing an "Order Details" table - typically, an order has several order details, and each of the order details then maps to a product - something like the sample in Northwind:

[image]

In that case, your SQL query would be something like this: join the `[Order Details]` table to both the `[Orders]` and `[Products]` tables, group by the product ID and name, and count the OrderID's:

```
select 
    p.ProductID, p.ProductName, count(o.OrderID)
from
    [order details] od
inner join
    orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
inner join
    products p ON od.productID = p.ProductID
group by
    p.ProductID, p.ProductName
having
    count(o.OrderID) > 50
```

Comment: Possibly add `having count(*) > 50` to satisfy the OP's original question?